# DirPagination Unknown provider error [Minified issue]

Tags: angularjs, minify, dirpagination

I have implemented DirPagination in angularJs and it is working fine locally, but when I deployed it on server, it throws error

```
[$injector:unpr]
```

I assume this is minified version related issue, as on server my all js files including controller and app are using minified version,

**Implementation** 
Simply indluded dirPagination.js file and pagination html file
Then after

```
var App= angular.module('App', ['ngRoute', 'use', 'ngMessages', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

Then
**In View**

```
 <li dir-paginate="u in list| filter:q | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">
```

And it is working with non-minified version.

**Update**

I confirmed this is minified version issue, as when I removed app and controller js min to non min files, it is working.

Any help how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't use the synthax to **keep your code right when minified**.

When minifying, all the injections are remplaced with shorter names.
Let's take an example.

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $location) { ... });
```

When minified will be transform to:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function(a, b) { ... });
```

As you can see, you lost the dependancies names.

---

JavaScript variables are renamed, but strings stay unchange. You should change it to this synthax (as [advice by the Angular team](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)):

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) { ... }]);
```

Comment: I have not done any thing in controller I just included this module. let me update the question

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam I took a controller as an exemple, but it will be the same for your whole app. Updated my answer to be clearer.

Comment: I have updated the code base, I have just started learning and implementing angularJS so may be I did not understand

Comment: Could you please update my given code base where should I made any change, because I am only including the module only. rest all things are being done by plugin

Comment: The module declaration you provided is correct. The problem comes from another part of your app.

Comment: Rest everything is inside plugin https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/master/src/directives/pagination/dirPagination.js

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam After looking at the code, it does not respect the standard I evoked in my answer: this code can't be minified.

Comment: Does it mean this plugin cannot be used with minified files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142827/discussion-between-mistalis-and-md-parvez-alam).